# A SQL Query which display Name of Area having max Employees

Tags: sql

I have a table

`Employee (EmpId, EmpName,AreaId)`

and table

`Area (AreaId,AreaName)`

AreaId will be the foreign key in Employee table.

I want a SQL Query which displays name of area having maximum number of Employees are working.

Comment: Have you tried any SQL yet?  It would be easier if you showed us a) what you've tried and b) something more about your DB than just names/columns.

Comment: What if two areas have the same maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 areaname
from area
    inner join employee 
    on area.areaid=employee.areaid
group by areaname
order by count(*) desc
```

Or as appropriate for your variety of sql (eg: LIMIT for mySQL)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

You just need to use the GroupBY staement with MAX() function

```
SELECT   TOP 1 AreaName
FROM     area a join Employee e
ON       a.AreaId=e.AreaId
GROUP BY AreaName
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```